# Mocking react-native-keychain, undefined is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs, react-native-keychain

I'm trying to write a test for my helper functions, which uses the react-native-keychain Library.

I accordingly to the [documentation](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain#unit-testing-with-jest) mocked the library.

I added a directory react-native-keychain to the `__mocks__` directory and added the following code:

```
const keychainMock = {  
SECURITY_LEVEL_ANY: 'MOCK_SECURITY_LEVEL_ANY',
SECURITY_LEVEL_SECURE_SOFTWARE: 'MOCK_SECURITY_LEVEL_SECURE_SOFTWARE',
SECURITY_LEVEL_SECURE_HARDWARE: 'MOCK_SECURITY_LEVEL_SECURE_HARDWARE',
setGenericPassword: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(),
getGenericPassword: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(),
resetGenericPassword: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(),
};
export default keychainMock;
```

My helper function calls the getGenericPassword method.

```
{
getGenericPassword().then(genericPassword => {
  if (genericPassword) {
    setUser({jwt: genericPassword.password, authorities: []});
  }
});
}
```

and my test looks like this:

```
describe('AuthProvider', () => {

test('Snapshot', () => {
const component = renderer.create(
  <AuthProvider>
    <MockComponent />
  </AuthProvider>,
);

expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I get the following error when running the tests:

```
TypeError: (0 , _reactNativeKeychain.getGenericPassword) is not a function
```

Package.json:

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.1",
"react-native-keychain": "^8.0.0",
"jest": "26.6.3",
```

So the mocks seem to work since its not calling the real method, but the jest.fn() neither.

What am i missing?

Comment: The mock leverages default export, are you also importing the default export, and not a named one?